# Bounds for maximum number of code-words in a ternary error correcting code with length n and distance d?

Tags: coding-theory

I'm not sure I can find an explicit formula. Wondering if anyone can come up with lower/upper bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact answer is unknown in general. One standard upper bound for $q-$ary codes is the Singleton bound, which gives
$$|C|\leq q^{n-d+1},$$ and codes meeting this bound are called MDS.

A lower bound is the Gilbert-Varshamov bound, given by

$$|C|\geq \frac{q^n}{\mathrm{Vol}_q(d-1)}=\frac{q^n}{\sum_{k=0}^{d-1} \binom{n}{k}(q-1)^k}.$$
Using these keywords should get you started, there are many more results.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking for asymptotic results, there are extensive tables that are maintained by researchers.

You can find them at [www.codetables.de](http://www.codetables.de). Go to that webpage, and click "linear codes". They have complete tables of known upper and lower bounds for linear GF(3) (ternary) codes with $n \leq 243$.